# Toolbar - findViewbyID returning null

Tags: android, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

Why am I unable to find my `Toolbar` in my layout?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

After that, toolbar is still null.

activity_man.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools.context=".PlayerActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        : (goes on)
```

EDIT:

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is in `res/layout/toolbar.xml`? `R.id.toolbar` is pointing to an `<include>`, not a `Toolbar`. "In my Toolbar layout there's only the Toolbar" -- but this layout is not part of your question, and so we cannot see its contents.

Comment: Are you using `setContentView` for toolbar.xml?

Comment: Updated with setcontenview and toolbar layout.
I played around a bit and now it's working but the Toolbar is not visible on the screen?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is working fine you may not have disable default actionbar:

Change the following in styles.xml to remove action bar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

Bring toolbar to front using `toolbar.bringToFront();`

Comment: Already removed! I guess that the @+id/background_image ImageView is preventing the Toolbar to show up, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Try this method toolbar.bringToFront();